# Passing String Array parameter to the MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, controller

I have the following controller to take four parameter and one to get an array of string.

```
public Response Get(string a, double b, double c, string[] d)
{
   do something
}
```

As u see the fourth(d) parameter is an array of strings. The first 3 parameter get the value but d shows null.

I am using fiddler to debug with following  url

```
04/api/Controller?a=Hello&b=-37.8031231&c=144.9836514&d=Italian&d=bars
```

What m i doing wrong? is it the url?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your View, I can abstract that you named 2 inputs as name='d' without indexing

example:

You can create an array by naming your id inputs with array indexes.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="d[1]">
    <input type="text" name="d[2]">
}
```

If you index your inputs, the framework will use them as a List

**Note:**
you bring up URL. You cannot pass an array or any complex object without a Post.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply. I dont have an index yet just a controller and m using fiddler. Thats a manually typed url.. So how should my url look like? i mean should i use /api/Controller?a=Hello&b=-37.8031231&c=144.9836514&d1=Italian&d2=bars

Comment: @user2094169, you CANNOT pass an array to a controller with URL. You have to use a Form.

Comment: OIC, Thank for the tip. Goodday

Comment: @user2094169, I altered my answer to include an example of a Razor form that would create an array. Would you be able to use this?

Answer (score 1):

You can post array data from fiddler, the URL you have provided is correct. But make sure you have the correct **content type** in request header.

you don't have to create view to test your controller action method.

**Client request**

[image]

**Server respone**

[image]

P.S. Above provided is for controller action method, I have noticed you are using api controller after posting the answer. I will edit the answer once done for api controller.

**The Above works for APIController as well, If you are posting from fiddler**